# Multilocale Chapel: make check fails (GASNet: Invalid number of nodes: -nl)

Tags: chapel, gasnet

I'm trying to run Chapel in multi-locale mode with Slurm.
However, 'make check' fails.
Could someone help me with that?

I used Chapel 1.23.0. Here are the actual commands I used:

```
cd chapel-1.23.0/
export CHPL_HOME=$PWD
source $CHPL_HOME/util/setchplenv.bash
export CHPL_COMM=gasnet
export CHPL_LAUNCHER=slurm-srun
export CHPL_TARGET_CPU=native
make && make check
```

Here is the error messages I got:

```
== Actual Test Output (raw, with verbose) ==
srun --job-name=CHPL-hello6-tas --quiet --nodes=4 --ntasks=4 --ntasks-per-node=1 --cpus-per-task=16 --exclusive --mem=0 --kill-on-bad-exit  /home/user1/.chpl/chapel-test-P4CwK/hello6-taskpar-dist_real -nl4 --printLocaleName=false -v
GASNet: Invalid number of nodes: -nl4
GASNet: Usage '/home/user1/.chpl/chapel-test-P4CwK/hello6-taskpar-dist_real <num_nodes> {program arguments}'
```

Comment: To find out if the problem is specific to `make check`, could you check if the following command works?

`chpl examples/hello6-taskpar-dist.chpl && ./hello6-taskpar-dist -nl 4`

Comment: I was able to fix the issue but, just FYI, I got the same error with `hello6-taskpar-dist`. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the udp substrate with gasnet (`$CHPL_HOME/util/printchplenv` shows `CHPL_COMM_SUBSTRATE: udp`) then slurm-srun doesn't work in that particular configuration. The udp substrate requires `CHPL_LAUNCHER=amudprun`. From https://chapel-lang.org/docs/platforms/udp.html#using-the-udp-conduit-with-slurm, you should be able to do:

```
export CHPL_LAUNCHER=amudprun
export GASNET_SPAWNFN=C
export GASNET_CSPAWN_CMD="srun -N%N %C"
```

Note that you'll have to redo the top-level `make` command.

This tells Chapel to use the `amudprun` launcher, and then lets `amudprun` know how to spawn onto this system (in this case using srun instead of defaulting to using ssh)

Comment: Is this something that the `chplenv` scripts or Makefiles could check for and issue an error against to prevent future users from potentially stepping into this hole?

Comment: Yeah, that's a possibility. I opened https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/16971 to look into that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It worked!